# lua_tostring not working in SQL function in c code

Tags: c, lua, lua-api

I'm trying to apply my entry in the lua in a code for sql in C.

My lua file has the following code:

```
prepare_sql = {
    flvdb = "flv_database";
};
```

My lua code is as follows:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "prepare_sql");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "flvdb");
p->flvdb = lua_tostring(L, -1);
```

My C code before applying lua code worked normally:

```
sql_prepare(SqlPrepare *stax, const char *qry, ...);
```

Before:

```
if(SQLPASS != sql_prepare(sqltp, "INSERT INTO `flv_database` (`date`, `value`, `count`) VALUES (NOW(), '%d', '%d')", p->value, p->cnt))
```

After:

```
if(SQLPASS != sql_prepare(sqltp, "INSERT INTO `%s` (`date`, `value`, `count`) VALUES (NOW(), '%d', '%d')", p->flvdb, p->value, p->cnt))
```

Before the code worked well, after applying lua he can't capture the name that is in the file. Does anyone have an idea of what can be?

Comment: try `printf("%s", p->flvdb)` to see what's in there

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but I did it and it returns the correct name, equal is in the file, but when you apply sql function does not work

Comment: Don't you need to do "`prepare_sql = {`" instead of "`prepare_sql {`"? Is it a typo in your question only?

Comment: Sorry the file is correct, my mistake when creating the topic.

Comment: Define "doesn't work" at this point? What isn't working? Can you use a debugger or other tool to see exactly what is being passed into `sql_prepare` at that point?

Answer (score 2):

Because you cannot prepare a query with a variable table name.
Your Lua code is ok.

Comment: so they would need some complex (and probably still escaping wrongly) sprintf magic?

Comment: @nonchip maybe sql_escape + sprintf